# Throttle the number of calls to a method

Tags: java, guava, sleep, throttling

In my code I send batch requests to a custom Database. 
The response time of the each batch is in milliseconds.

However I have a limitation on the number of batches I can send per second. Max of one batch. In case of additional batches, the batch would be dropped which is not what is desired.

I can use `Thread.sleep()` for a second so that I would never hit the database with more than one batch per second.

The pseudo code looks like :

```
createBatch()
sendBatch()
```

What I am trying to do is limit the number of times `sendBatch()` is called in a second.

Can I achieve this using any throttling library rather than using `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: Well have you looked at any throttling libraries?

Comment: I considered Guava but haven't understood how to use it to my scenario.
Also i am not asking about limiting resources . I only wish to control the number of method hits . This method is supposed to be hit sequentially . 
Based on some criteria this method might take too less or too long time. 
I wish to make sure that there is an upper limit on the number of method hits in a particular duration of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RateLimiter from guava.
see: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

Comment: Currently i am doing this using guava ratelimiter. 
    RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(1.0);
    rateLimiter.acquire();
    performOperation();



By the above code , i wish to call the method performOperation() only once per second. 

However the method is getting called continuously irrespective of the ratelimit specified. 

Could you please tell me how i can control the number of method hits in the above snippet .

Comment: You shouldn't create a new RateLimiter for every performOperation() call. Instead define a single RateLimiter and use it.

Comment: Hi Mustafa,
The solution worked. But i would like to know one thing. When i created a RateLimiter outside the method and used it inside it by passing it as param , it worked. However when i defined a ratelimiter inside a method and tried to use it within the method just before making another method call , then it did not work. Could you please tell me why this is so?

Comment: Because new RateLimiter means a new "allow one call per second" permission.

Comment: Im sorry . I did not quite understand .
In the case that worked . I passed RateLimiter as a parameter to a method and used the RateLimiter to  the calls to another method that were made inside the method that has RateLimter as  a parameter. 

in the second case , instead of passing the RateLimiter as a parameter , i declared it inside the method and used it trottle the calls to another method which is called from inside this method.

How does it matter if I pass RateLimiter as a parameter or declare it just before the place at which the method calls are made?

Answer (score 1):

i think this is problem of limiting number resources that can be utilized at a time. Try using pooling technique. in java you can use ExecutorService to do the same. Refer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
here is sample code

```
class Worker implements Callable<String> {
private int id;
public Worker(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    System.out.println("im worker = " + id);
}
public String call() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Started some long operation - " + id);
    Thread.sleep(1000); // only to simulate long running operation
    System.out.println("Fiished long operation - " + id);
    return null;
}
```

}

// main mehtod

```
public class Main {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    final int poolSize = 100;
    final int workerSize = 1000;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    Future[] futures = new Future[workerSize];
    Worker[] workers = new Worker[workerSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < workerSize; i++){
        workers[i] = new Worker(i);
    }
    System.out.println("finished creating workers================");
    for(int i = 0; i < workerSize; i++){
        futures[i] = executor.submit(workers[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < workerSize; i++){
        futures[i].get();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished executing all");
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: Im already using executor service to control the number of threads . In the above question i am actually trying to control the number of times a method is called in a particular period of time.